# Build App with Xamarin Studio -> German Umlaute in CFBundleDisplayName shown as "?"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

when I build my App with Xamarin Studio, German Umlaute shown as “?”. When I build the App with Mono Develop everything is fine.

For Example: Tür -> T?r
Does anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This a bug in Xamarin Studio's plist writer. It will be fixed in version 4.0.2.